# GCP Vector Search: deploy an index to an index endpoint via Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, vector-search

I have created a Vector Search Index and an Index Endpoint in GCP via Terraform by using those modules:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/vertex_ai_index
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/vertex_ai_index_endpoint

Now I want to deploy the index to the index endpoint. The gcloud command would be (as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai/index-endpoints/deploy-index)):

```
$ gcloud ai index-endpoints deploy-index ...
```

I did not find a possibility to do this via Terraform. Does anybody know if this is possible?

Thanks & kind regards.